# How to get current class's field base on object type using reflection?

Tags: java, reflection

I have a class that have many Label, String and int fields. Inside a method I want to loop through all Label only.
Class sample as below:

```
public class Human{

    Label lbl1;
    Label lbl2;
    Label lbl3;
    String str1;
    int i1;

    public void loadLbl(){
         //load all Label only
    }
}
```

Below is the code I working now, but couldn't get the right syntax to get the fields. **This code will run inside of loadLbl()**.

```
Field[] fields=Human.class.getDeclaredFields(); // get all declared fields

for(Field field:fields){
     if(field.getType().equals(Label.class)){ // if it is a String field
      field.setAccessible(true);
      //work here             
     }
}
```

Comment: Reflection is really, really not a good idea here (as almost always). Just store your labels in a listt, and iterate over the list.

Comment: @JBNizet I am doing some light code to speed up a development process. I know the risk

Comment: This is the right syntax to get fields base on object type. What's not working?

Comment: @amicoderozer You're right , I have imported the libgdx reflection package. And that screwed it up. Switched back to import java.lang.reflect.Field; do fix the compiler error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could change from **Human.class**  to reference object like **new Human(),** it should work.

like below :

```
Field[] fields=new Human().getClass().getDeclaredFields();
```

**Edited :**

Or dont use additional method **getClass()** in your code.

like below:

```
 Field[] fields=Human.class.getDeclaredFields();
```

Comment: The code will be execute inside of Human class , updated question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Class  aClass = MyObject.class
Field field = aClass.getField("someField");

MyObject objectInstance = new MyObject();

Object value = field.get(objectInstance);

field.set(objetInstance, value);
```

Comment: if field is private - use Getters

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer from Raju Sharma is correct, or maybe your question isn't clear enough. The full function will be like that.

```
public void loadLbl()
    {
        // load all Label only
        Field[] fields = new Human().getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field : fields)
        {
            if (field.getType().equals(Label.class))
            {
                System.out.println(field.getName());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what if Human() has not public constructor? Or have externall effect? Instance is NOT required to reflection analyse (to call by invoke - yes)

Comment: But loadLbl() INSIDE Human class ( follow the question). If you can init Human, you can use this function. If loadLbl() outside , my answer isn't correct.